# How to use custom color

Tags: wpf

In my wpf application i want to use this custom color code **#7EC143** for my button background ....need help to set custom color code for background of button

Answer (score 12):

In your XAML just set it like so:

```
<Button Name="button1" Background="#7EC143">Foo</Button>
```

If you're trying to do it from code it's more like this:

```
button1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0x7e, 0xc1, 0x43));
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<Button Background="#7EC143" />
```